# Which is better QTP or Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Can anybody tell me,which tool is better.QTP or Jmeter?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Both aim at quite different use cases, it's sort of like comparing apples and oranges...

Comment: Some information that would be helpful includes:
 - What are you testing?
 - What kind of testing do you need? (Performance, Stress, simple automated)
 - What kind of experience do you have with automation
 - Is cost a factor?

Comment: I want to go into automation.As per my knowledge QTP is only for functional testing and JMETER can be used for performance,load and functional testing.But QTP is more popular than JMETER.And I am not sure whether JMETER can be used to test applications written in language other than JAVA.
Please help me choose anyone out of the two.

Comment: JMeter tests web-based applications. Not only ones in Java/J2EE - any web application using request/response. You like you need a automated regression test pack for which QTP is quite popular - but you can also test a repetitive pack with JMeter.

Comment: So U mean to say If I choose Jmeter I can do functional,performance,load testing for any kind of web application but this is less popular compared to QTP,though its better than QTP?

Comment: @SUMAIYA - no one has said JMeter is better than QTP. It depends on your needs : **QTP costs. JMeter is free.** Answer some of @BlackGaff questions and you can get a better reponse.

Comment: I just want to learn a tool,using which I can do functional testing,load testing and performance testing for the web-applications written in any current programming language.So can Jmeter be the right tool for fulfilling my needs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes for learning a tool to do functional testing,load testing and performance testing for the web-applications written in any current programming language as in OP's comment, [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) is a quick and easy and free tool to use.

You can point at any web application and record a script and just follow the instructions from the user manual